# SQL - Finding an hour of maximum activity

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying it different ways, but still don't know how to get this result(

[image]

**QRY_TYPE** (`ID` – unique identifier of type, `С_NAME` – name of type, `C_AB_REF` – link to the abonent, who processes these types of messages).

**ST_ABONENTS** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_NAME` – name)

**QRY_QUEUE** (`ID` – unique identifier, `С_IN_TIME` – date and time of writing msg into table, `C_EXEC_TIME` – date and time of the msg processing, `C_ST` – processing status (null - didn't, 1 – successfull, 0 – error with processing), `C_QRY_TYPE` – link for the query type).

I need to make SQL query, which will show an HOUR, when CNT(count of messages in this time is max) - in other words the most high loaded hour for all abonents.

Result should look like this

[image]

Comment: Hour of in_time, hour of exec_time, hour of difference?  I'm baffled by the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) AS hr
   ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
....
GROUP BY 
   EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME)
ORDER BY 
   COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

If you Oracle version doesn't support `FETCH`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
    SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME) AS hr
       ,COUNT(*) AS cnt
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rn
    FROM
    ....
    GROUP BY 
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM C_EXEC_TIME)
  ) dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: @Alexey: Hint, replace `SELECT *` :-)